# Folder view can not be changed on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

For some reason I cannot retain a particular view in the folders I have on my desktop. I would prefer to use an ICON view. I can change it to ICONS and then close the folder. When I reopen it it is back to list view. It used to work a while ago.

Comment: Do you want to apply the view to all of the folders on your computer, or just the ones on your desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the current view to all folders once you have it the way you like by using Microsoft's instructions below:

> To apply the current view setting to other folders
>
> While browsing folders in the Computer folder, you can apply the current view setting to all folders on your computer that are optimized for the same content as the folder you have open. For instance, the My Pictures folder is optimized for picture files. If you open this folder and change the view to Large Icons, you can apply the Large Icons view to every folder that's optimized for pictures. (This setting does not apply when viewing files and folders using libraries.)
>
> Open a folder, click the arrow next to the Views button  on the toolbar, and choose a view setting.
>
> On the toolbar, click Organize, and then click Folder and search options.
>
> In the Folder Options dialog box, click the View tab, click Apply to Folders, click Yes, and then click OK.
>
> Tip
>
> To change the type of file that a folder is optimized for, right-click the folder, click Properties, click the Customize tab, click a file type in the Optimize this folder for list, and then click OK.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-folder-options#section_3